# Paragraph Display in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

how to show paragraph data in android new activity 
on clicking  to show that data in text view.
But not using "HTML".

Comment: Please read the following article and adjust your question according to it http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a **`textview`**

```
TextView t = findViewById(R.id.text);

t.setText("This is the first line\nThis is the second line\nThird line...");
```

Comment: @onexf,his answerr also worked but he didn't set in textview.

Comment: @Salman if it helps you kindly mark this as an answer..happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to reference a string from the resource file(app->res->values->strings.xml).

XML file saved at `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="paragraph">This is my first big message!\n my second big message.</string>
</resources>
```

This layout XML applies a string to a View:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/paragraph" />
```

How the string is retrieved:

```
String string = getString(R.string.paragraph);
```